# How to correctly add daemon in MacOS 10.6.6 via launchd?

Tags: mac-osx, tomcat, launchd

I have a very simple task to accomplish: to start tomcat application server on latest MacOS as a daemon. I have performed following steps:

1. Installed Tomcat in /Library/Tomcat/Home
2. Validated that it runs fine by executed /Library/Tomcat/Home/bin/startup.sh
3. Added org.apache.tomcat.plist file to /Library/LaunchDaemons as found on internet (http://blog.i18n.ro/complete-guide-for-installing-hudson-ci-on-os-x-10-6/)
4. Instructed MacOS to load a daemon description via `sudo launchctl load org.apache.tomcat.plist`. It succeeded (issuing this command second time outputs "already loaded").
5. Instructed MacOS to start a daeon via `sudo launchctl start org.apache.tomcat.plist`

At this point MacOS shows an error "launchctl start error: No such process". I have checked the logfile for launchd - it have no record for this error. Google says nothing. And from error text i can't figure out what is the "process" and why it is "wrong" :(. Any hints what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where was an error in my setup. The correct start command is `sudo launchctl start org.apache.tomcat`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do

`launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.tomcat.plist`

or it won't automatically start on reboot.